# Redirecting Unique Visitors to an alternate Home Page?

Tags: redirect, seo

I am trying to redirect unique visitors going to my homepage/root domain *only* to an alternative version of my homepage.

I currently trying to do this on a Wordpress blog, but I have other Non-Wordpress sites to do this on as well.

What is the best way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called A/B testing and it can be done using an app like visualwebsiteoptimizer.com

Hope that helps, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try Nelio A/B Testing plugin for wordpress http://wordpress.org/plugins/nelio-ab-testing/